# Subclassing PFObject: Proper way to override dynamic getter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I use the following subclass of a PFObject:

```
//HEADER FILE
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface ParseMenuItem : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * menuItemDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * menuPortions; //Some other PFObjects...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * categories; //NSStrings

//...

@end


//IMPLEMENTATION FILE
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
#import "ParseMenuItem.h"
@implementation ParseMenuItem

@dynamic name, menuItemDescription, menuPortions, categories;

+ (NSString*) parseClassName {
    return @"MenuItem";
}

//...

@end
```

Every time I try to access `menuItem.categories` or `menuItem.menuPortions` where `menuItem` is a fetched object of type `ParseMenuItem`, the exception `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "categories" / "menuPortions" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'` is raised.

How can I customize the getters of these properties, so that it automatically fetches the data if needed?

I don't know how the dynamically generated getter looks like, so I don't know what I have to write to replace them whit some custom ones.

Is there a way to call the dynamically generated one in the one that I provide?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the key first to see if it's defined / has data before accessing it.  Having it fetch the data in the getter is a neat idea, but it would have to be asynchronous, so it couldn't return the value unless you provided a block.

You might be able to define a getter that at least safely checks without throwing:

```
-(NSString *) menuItemDescription {
  if (menuItemDescription) {
    return menuItemDescription;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

edit: have you tried doing the blocking fetch in the setter? something like:

```
-(NSArray *) categories {
  if (!categories) {
    [self fetchIfNeeded];
  }
  if (!categories) {
    return nil;
  }
  return categories;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question.
`menuItemDescription` isn't the problem and I don't want to make it asynchronous. I would like to make a blocking fetch.

Comment: This can't be compiled. Do you mean `_categories`? But then I have to synthesize this property and I am really not sure what happens, if I synthesize a property, that should be added dynamically... Basically I want to know how the dynamic version of the getter looks like, so I can use my own version of it, without loosing the functionality provided by parse.

Comment: I checked it. It isn't allowed to synthesize a dynamically provided property: `Property 'categories' is already implemented.`